# Is there a way to size a div portion of screen without javascript

Tags: html, css

I want to make a page that looks something like this, where I have a gray div (that I would put content in, of course) that takes up all of the screen but with a white margin on all sides.

[image: HTML Screenshot of what I want]

I would like it to be the perfect height on all screen sizes, but I'm not sure the best way to do this. I could potentially use JavaScript to adjust the height based on screen size, but I was curious if there was a better way to do it using CSS. I have seen lots of sites do similar things with a cover image, so it seems like there should be a simple CSS solution...

Comment: Have you tried `height: 100vh` ? It takes full height no matter what screen you are on.

Comment: Use width and height percentage values and give the div a margin or it’s parent some padding. Alternatively you can use vh and or vw units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```css
.navbar{
  height:calc(10vh - 2em);
  background-color:white;
  padding:1em;
  width:calc(100% - 2em);
}
body{
  background-color:white;
  margin:0;
}
.contents{
  height:calc(90vh - 2em);
  width:calc(100vw - 2em);
  margin:auto;
  background-color:#ededed;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">Branding</div>
<div class="contents"></div>
```

You can leverage `vh` (viewport height) and `vw` (viewport width) and `calc()` to dynamically calculate appropriate widths and heights without javascript.

Comment: Ooh that's even better! Then the margin is stack even on devices. I think I have used calc in the past, I just forgot it was a thing lol. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @dguis Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `width: 100wh` and `height: 100vh` which corresponds to the viewport width and height of the screen of the device.